# Make Python Scripts Tamper-proof

Tags: python, code-signing

I am executing python scripts using python embedding (python.net in C#), I need to make sure these python scripts aren't going to be tampered with. These python scripts can be in a .pyc (compiled) format.

Is there a way to make these scripts tamper-proof? .pyc files can be easily decompiled, tampered with and recompiled. I looked at signet but I believe it requires the python files to be frozen into an executable.

Any help will be welcome.

Comment: You may have a look at obfuscation. Here is a handy link: https://medium.com/geekculture/python-source-code-obfuscation-6b97f88a460d#:~:text=Obfuscation%20is%20one%20of%20the,binary%20libraries%20with%20no%20effort.

Comment: What sort of tampering, exactly, are you trying to prevent?  Are you trying to prevent an untrusted user from modifying your script and running it themselves, or are you trying to prevent an untrusted middleman from modifying your script and tricking someone else into running it, or...?

Comment: @Samwise I am trying to prevent anyone that could go in modify the script (by copying the script or modifying it) to use for their own use or that could help them access data they shouldn't access

Comment: I would discourage usage of obfuscation, as it's not reliable (it will only prevent non-motivated attackers). Instead, you could simply sign these scripts. There are general-purpose cryptographic libraries that already provide these functionalities, see for example [gpg](https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x135.html).

Comment: @qwerty How could your script be used to access data they shouldn't have access to? Does your code contain secrets/keys?

Comment: @IainShelvington it does not, but they can tamper the data to output the result of the script to save data on the local machine or some other machine.

Comment: You're worried that you might run a script that has been tampered with without knowing? Where is the script stored/retrieved from such that this is even a possibility? If someone is able to modify your scripts/code unauthorised then that seems like a bigger issue

Comment: @IainShelvington yes exactly, the script is stored in the users machine where the application is stored

Comment: @BlackBeans I agree with the obfuscation part. If you can post something regarding gpg and python scripts, I can accept that as an answer.

Comment: @qwerty I think, reading your question, that you want to use GPG from C#, not python (if I understood correctly), and since I don't know C# I just linked to a post where they explain better than I could how to do that.

Comment: @BlackBeans thank you, I am actually trying to create a detached sig from command line and then verify it using a python script. Any pointers?

Comment: @qwerty look in the GPG documentation. It has a command line utility, and Python bindings.

Comment: @BlackBeans Yup, I managed to figure it out, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is signing these scripts. Signing a file means producing a signature from a private key and that file, the idea being that it's impossible to produce that same signature without the private key. Then, you also have a public key (that can be made public), whose only purpose is to verify that the signature matches the file. IIRC, this is the same mechanism that Windows uses to trust software (ie. there are software developers who are trusted by Windows, and when a software has a signature issued by a trusted source, which Windows can verify, then it is considered as trusted software, I think).

This is quite a common cryptographic pattern, so I think there are many tools that implement it, but one that is particularly good is GPG. It's free and open-source, it has bindings in many languages, it is very well documented, and handles everything, from the creation of your key pair to the signing, and much more. This also mean that using GPG is a little bit complex, but I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58286540/verify-a-detached-pgp-signature-in-c-sharp) where someone wanted to verify a file they download in C# using GPG, so maybe it's going to be helpful.

Also, notice that in that in the other post they also use a hash check to ensure that the script was not corrupted during download (ie. there was a download error). You could verify that with the signature, but then you would be unable to tell if the error comes from someone deliberately attempting to tamper with your code, or if you just need to re-download the script.